# MutationObserver hangs if I use setAttribute

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have an observer, which listens any changes of attributes of `listitem` divs, and if attibutes is changed, it will set background color of that div to red.

*Actually you can easily test it yourself. Open Chrome's bookmark manager, launch this script in console, and then click any bookmark or folder. It will be colored red.*

The problem is mentioned in the middle of the code block: if I use `setAttribute`, the script will be hanged.

The first method (using `style.attributeName`) is not appropriate for me, because in my actual code I use custom attribute, not `background-color`.

The problem looks very strange. What's the way it may be solved?

```
<div role="listitem"></div>
<div role="listitem"></div>
<div role="listitem"></div>

<script>
var target = document.querySelectorAll("[role='listitem']");
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {


            // The Problem
            // ===========

            // This work well
            mutation.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";

            // But this doesn't
            // mutation.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");

        });
    });

    // configuration of the observer
    var config = { attributes: true };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(target[i], config);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're responding to every attribute change by changing an attribute. It's no surprise that that causes a problem: You'll make the observer fire again. Apparently `setAttribute` updates the attribute object even though you're setting the same value (which I suppose isn't unreasonable, though it's a bit surprising).

Instead, I would only set it if it actually needs to change:

```
if (mutation.target.getAttribute("yourattr") != targetvalue) {
    mutation.target.setAttribute("yourattr", targetvalue);
}
```

I've checked that setting the attribute to the same value *does* fire the observer again (on Chrome, anyway):

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
var counter = 0;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    ++counter;
    console.log(Date.now() + ": " + counter);
    if (counter < 10) {
        console.log("Inside handler: Setting data-foo to bar");
        target.setAttribute("data-foo", "bar");
    } else {
        console.log("Inside handler: Stopped, to avoid looping forever");
    }
});
observer.observe(target, {attributes: true});
console.log("Initial change: Setting data-something-else to testing");
target.setAttribute("data-something-else", "testing");
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

So checking first prevents that happening:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    console.log(Date.now() + ": In handler");
    if (target.getAttribute("data-foo") != "bar") {
        console.log("Inside handler: Setting data-foo to bar");
        target.setAttribute("data-foo", "bar");
    } else {
        console.log("Inside handler: No need to set it, it's already set");
    }
});
observer.observe(target, {attributes: true});
console.log("Initial change: Setting data-something-else to testing");
target.setAttribute("data-something-else", "testing");
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```